# Sky Go keeps asking me to activate Silverlight

Tags: 14.10, pipelight, moonlight

Can anyone please help?  I am trying to watch Sky Go from my Ubuntu 14.10 PC.  I have installed pipelight, etc. using a variety of instructions I have found online.

Everything seems to have installed, but when I go to the Sky Website and try and launch a programme, I still get the prompt to "Activate Silverlight".  Sorry, I can't attach a screenshot as the forum rules will not let me.

I have tried this via Firefox and chrome, and also with the agent switcher extensions set to mimic Firefox on Wondows), but still to no avail.

Can anyone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: This question and all answers are all irrelevant now since in Aug 2019 Sky have released a new Sky Go player which is no longer based on Silverlight and instead based on Cisco's Video Player and after years of customer complaints that it only ever worked on Windows, their new offering is compatible with Windows and Mac OSX only.  It supports the range of Microsoft and Apple PC's /TAB's & Phones but NOT Android/Linux.  I am not sure if possible to get the Sky Go Video Player to run on Wine, but in any case, that would need to be an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Moonlight only supports Silverlight 4.0 (this information is in the official website), You need Silverlight 5.0. Try using "fork-project" on Winepholio, or only (its information is included in this [Pipelight tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html).

Follow all the tutorial, and don't skip any of the steps.

After installing Pipelight, you need to install Silverlight 5.1 in Wine, and after this install and enable plugin (in Firefox or Chrome); look for the plugin manager options Enable or Disable Silverlight.

[This tutorial](https://silicondales.com/tutorials/use-sky-go-silverlight-5-video-ubuntu-linux/) will allow the potential online video viewer who has made the decision to use Ubuntu to actually watch video online when it is in the format Silverlight 5+ (currently, at the time of writing, we're on Silverlight 5.1).

Answer (score 0):

Check Silverlight is actually activated (rather than just installed) in Firefox add-ons plug-ins. You may need to changer from 'ask to activate' to 'always activate'.